# How do I put a table following the other table in a two-colmuns layout?

Tags: tables, align, two-column

my page is of two columns layout and I want to put two tables in consequence on the right column like below:

```
text here    Table 1 goes here
text here
text here    Table 2 goes here
text here
```

while I have used `wraptable` then Table 1 is placed accurate but Table 2 is jumped to the left column below the last text line. In case if I remove `wraptable` for the table 2, the two tables are covering each other (overlapping).

How can I have the two tables aligned in the right column?

Comment: You can use a single `table` environment containing two `tabular` (and two `\caption`)

Comment: Sounds much to complicated. I'd say, end multicols, use addmargin to get a broad margin and put the tables right beside the text in a marginpar, restart multicols. But without a MWE, difficult to say...

Comment: @JLDiaz, it doesn't work if I do so.

Comment: @Sara, could you please provide a minimal document example which shows how it is not working?

Comment: you should be able to use one table environment with two `\caption` or two table environments. Either way (by default) you can not stop it going in the left column other than by moving the environments later in the source file. If that does not work you will need to post a complete document that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to adjust the position of your table environments in the source to avoid the left column, but otherwise it should just work with no special markup:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\def\a{One two three four five six even eight nine ten. }
\def\b{Red. \a\a Blue \a\a Green. \a\a\a}

\begin{document}

\listoftables


\b\b\b\b\b\a\b\b\b

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}1&2\\3&4\\5&6\end{tabular}
\caption{a table}
\end{table}
\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}11&22\\33&44\\55&66\end{tabular}
\caption{another table}
\end{table}

\b\b\b

\b\b\b\b\b\b

\end{document}
```