# How to arrange several tables in a two column article?

Tags: tables, two-column

In case of my previous question in [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188366/how-do-i-put-a-table-following-the-other-table-in-a-two-colmuns-layout) I have a question:

For a page of my article I should have two columns of text, where on the right column there are two tables following each other. and the page looks like this:

```
text here text here text here             table 1
text here text here text here
text here text here text here             table 2

 -table 3 in same width as the page, goes here-
 -table 4 in same width as the page, goes here-
```

I used `multicols` with `wraptable` but the tables are remained in left column although I put the alignment to the right by `{r}`

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\setlength{\columnsep}{25 pt} % Distance between two columns
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.9} % Determines the lightness of the watermark color
\SetWatermarkText{\textsf{\textbf{PRELIMINARY}}}
\SetWatermarkScale{0.7} % Specifies the size of the watermark
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} % page layout
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\noindent\underline{\textbf{Control and Data Interface}}\\

\noindent Both data and control is supported through a single interface enabling simple integration to a dedicated controller or microprocessor. \\

\noindent\underline{\textbf{Communication information}}\\

\noindent Our device allows a wide range of data rates over the interface, enabled by registery depending on clock rates and other settings, shown in the table 2.\\

\noindent \underline{\textbf{Top Level Performance}}\\

\noindent Overall performance and final image information are available in our website.

\columnbreak

\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
 \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Functional and Performance Parameters}} \\
  \hline
Parameter & Value & Unit \\ 
\hline
Pixel Representation & 8 & bit \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Functional and Performance Parameters}


\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{System Requirements}} \\
  \hline
Parameter & Min & Max & Unit \\ 
\hline
System Clock & 12 & 32 & MHz \\
\hline
Spin Clock & - & 24 & MHz \\
\hline
Digital Supply (Nominal) & 3.0 & 3.3 & V \\
\hline
Analog Supply (Nominal) & 3.0 & 3.3 & V \\
\hline
Digital IO Supply  & 1, 2 , 3.3 &  & V \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\
\caption{System Requirements}
\end{wraptable}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{table*}
\noindent\underline{\textbf{Operating Modes}}\\\\
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|l|X|Xr|}
\hline
\textbf{Active Modes} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline
Device on & The device can be on if you plug it to electricity. The setting - can be configured easily. The text here is long that's why I used tabluarx to fit it with the page width.\\
\hline
Image type & The final image is of png format and should be converted to jpeg first to process automatically by the device.
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}



\begin{table*}
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|l|X|Xr|}
\hline
\textbf{Inactive Modes} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline
Power on & Power on is activated whenever you reset the device. It doesn't react to the commands over the control interface.\\ \hline

Standby & This is activated in default. You can change the setting by commands from the control interface and its functionality maybe enabled by register setting.\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}\\
\end{table*}


\underline{\textbf{Mode Transition Times}}\\

\noindent The table below defines typical delays associated with mode transitions.\\

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

How can I arrange tables in this way as shown above?

Comment: **I added my sample tables script**

Comment: Please fix the example so people can run it `\documentclass` and any needed packages. Using `\\ ` outside of tables is almost always incorrect and using it at the end of a pararagraph is always incorrect (you must have had latex screaming about underful hboxes?)

Comment: Since in each row I have to draw a line in table, then `\\\` is useful. No, it is not screaming, hehe. Is there any alternative to use at end of paragraph then?

Comment: The reason for not using _twocolumn_ than the _multicols_ is due to having a text line (aligned in center) and a horizontal line right after the header in first page.

Comment: The `\\ ` inside the tabular are OK, all the ones outside the tabular were incorrect and _do_ produce warnings in your original example.

Comment: there are pros and cons between multicols and the standard twocolumn but the reason you give doesn't really help decide as you can do that with either.

Comment: The alternative to putting  an incorrect `\\ ` at the end of the paragraph is simply not to put `\\ ` there. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the `\documentclass` line (although it is in errror, `article` does not have a 9pt option).

Comment: Your edited document produces `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Comment: each of your `\\ ` produces `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 29--30` which is "screaming" (10000= _infinitely bad_)

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all the spurious `\\` which generate warnings from latex (and bad output) and removed wrapfig, you were specifying text in a column less than .5\textwidth wide (because of the column separation) to wraparound a table specified as `.5\textwidth`.

I shrank the text in the tables a bit but they are still too wide to fit in the two column area

Overfull \hbox (35.97255pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 37--52

but using subject knowledge you can probably shrink further or reformat.

Don't use `\noindent` The class design should be specifying where indentation is needed, if you are having to over-ride the design every line, something is wrong.

I also used `\label` to refer to the table rather than use `2` explicitly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol,tabularx,capt-of}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\section*{Control and Data Interface}

Both data and control is supported through a single interface enabling simple integration to a dedicated controller or microprocessor. 

\section*{Communication information}

Our device allows a wide range of data rates over the interface, enabled by registery depending on clock rates and other settings, shown in the table \ref{tz}.

\section*{Top Level Performance}

Overall performance and final image information are available in our website.

\columnbreak

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
Parameter & Value & Unit \\ 
\hline
Pixel Rep. & 8 & bit \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Functional and Performance Parameters\label{ty}}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
Parameter & Min & Max & Unit \\ 
\hline
System Clock & 12 & 32 & MHz \\
\hline
Spin Clock & - & 24 & MHz \\
\hline
Dig. Sup. (Nom.) & 3.0 & 3.3 & V \\
\hline
An. Sup. (Nom.) & 3.0 & 3.3 & V \\
\hline
Dig. IO Supply  & 1, 2, 3.3 &  & V \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{\label{tz}System Requirements}
\end{center}

\end{multicols}

\section*{Operating Modes}
\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|l|X||}
\hline
\textbf{Active Modes} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline
Device on & The device can be on if you plug it to electricity. The setting - can be configured easily. The text here is long that's why I used tabluarx to fit it with the page width.\\
\hline
Image type & The final image is of png format and should be converted to jpeg first to process automatically by the device.
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Inactive Modes} & \textbf{Description} \\
\hline
Power on & Power on is activated whenever you reset the device. It doesn't react to the commands over the control interface.\\ \hline

Standby & This is activated in default. You can change the setting by commands from the control interface and its functionality maybe enabled by register setting.\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section*{Mode Transition Times}

The table below defines typical delays associated with mode transitions.\\

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are perfect, thanks alot. It works well!